# Why QEMU gives "Permission denied" when trying to commit to a snapshot?

Tags: permissions, qemu

---

I'm running QEMU in full emulation mode with a QCOW2 image with `-snapshot`

I can make changes to the machine, and when i terminate the instance, the QCOW2 image is still on the original state.

But if I want to persist my changes, I connect to the telnet "Qemu monitor" and try the `commit` command. But it will always give me permission denied

```
(qemu) snapshot_blkdev ide0-hd0 snap0
snapshot_blkdev ide0-hd0 snap0
Error: Could not create 'snap0': Permission denied
(qemu) commit all
commit all
'commit' error for 'all': Permission denied
(qemu) info block
info block
ide0-hd0 (#block698): json:{"backing": {"driver": "qcow2", "file": {"driver": ")
    Attached to:      /machine/unattached/device[24]
    Cache mode:       writeback, ignore flushes
    Backing file:     ./arch-x86.qcow2 (chain depth: 1)

ide1-cd0: [not inserted]
    Attached to:      /machine/unattached/device[25]
    Removable device: not locked, tray closed

floppy0: [not inserted]
    Attached to:      /machine/unattached/device[19]
    Removable device: not locked, tray closed

sd0: [not inserted]
    Removable device: not locked, tray closed
```

the qemu-system process is owned by user id 1000.
the qcow2 file and directory it lives (which is also the path of the qemu process) are all owned and writable by user id 1000.

full cmd `qemu-system-x86_64 -machine pc,vmport=off,mem-merge=off,dump-guest-core=off,kernel-irqchip=split -smp 4 -m 1G,slots=4,maxmem=8G -name vma -monitor tcp:127.0.0.1:9901,server,nowait -display none -daemonize -nic user,id=n1,ipv6=off,hostname=vma,hostfwd=tcp::9922-:22 -snapshot -boot c -drive file=./arch-x86.qcow2,index=0,media=disk,format=qcow2`

Comment: You could try to `strace` qemu.

Comment: will add. meanwhile. running qemu *without* snapshot (either on main flags, and in drive flags) causes `commit all` to work just fine! ...but since i'm not snapshoting, i'm lost why i would even want to commit anything if it is already all committed by default.

Comment: @zomega i'm not that proficient with strace, but to run it i tried without the `-daemonize` flag... and then the `-snapshot` stops working. everything is always written to the main image as if the `-snapshot` flag was not even there.

Comment: then run it with "-daemonize" and attach strace to the dameon. If it doesn't work attach it to the qemu client. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482076/how-does-strace-connect-to-an-already-running-process

Answer (score 0):

Possible that's related on the follow bug:

- https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1151718

Possible that's has been fixed here:

- https://git.qemu.org/?p=qemu.git;a=commitdiff;h=4b25a50674de41e72f6b3003

Comment: i shouldn't be using any libvirt code with the setup described above?